# Visual Studio Online (Adjust User Privileges - not TFS user but windows user)

Tags: c++, tfsbuild, azure-devops

Today I encountered a very strange issue and google unfortunately did not help me. I have a project in VSTS Online and I configured it to run tests during the build, part of my tests are integration-tests (they run simple scenarios and test application state during the execution) and the problem is that my application uses AWE (Address Windows Extensions) for memory allocation and to use it windows user should have SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege - and VSTS Online user does not have it.

Can someone advice me how I can adjust privileges of the windows user in VSTS?

P.S.
My application automatically tries to adjust current user privileges through the code and gets access denied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Hosted Build Agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to adjust the privilege if you are using [Hosted Build Agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-agent-pool).

> Q: Do any of the processes for your build need administrator
>   privileges?
>
> A: No. Then you can use the hosted pool.
>
> Q: Do you need to log on to the build server?
>
> A: No. Then you can use the hosted pool.

You need to [deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows) to do this.

Comment: Thank you. I have deployed my agent but how do I trigger a build on it?

Comment: @AlehKarasik When you deploy your build agent, it should ask you to select which agent pool to place your build agent. The default setting is "Default" pool. When you queue a build, you can select the agent pool where your build agent hosted.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Can you advice me regarding one more thing? How can I run visual c++ tests for x64 platform during the build?